# (Cocoa) What's the equivalent of a UIViewController subclass in a single window cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

After messing around with iOS apps, I thought I'd give a Cocoa app a whirl assuming things would be very similar. So I have a single window app with a split view and some `NSTableView`s (think iTunes) and I'm looking for a place to put my code that will fetch data from the web to fill the tables.

In iOS I would put this in the `viewDidLoad` method of the appropriate `UIViewController` subclass. The `UITableViewDataSource` would then access this data to populate its cells.

Now I have an `NSWindow` for which I could do a similar thing but how do I make a `NSWindowController` for it? Is this even what I want? I could put it in the `AppDelegate` but doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between iOS and OS X is that there's only one window in iOS but there can be multiple in OS X. `NSViewControllers` in OS X work differently than `UIViewControllers`in that the `NSViewController` is designed to load and handle a single view, while `UIViewControllers` (apologies for my relative lack of iOS knowledge) seem to handle multiple views and provide much more of the glue between views.

Even the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html) write that:

> In Mac OS X, AppKit view controllers are assistants to the window
>   controller, which is ultimately responsible for everything that goes
>   in the window.

Hence, the counterpart for `UIViewController` in OS X isn't `NSViewController`, but rather `NSWindowController`, which does provide for OS X much of what `UIViewController` does for iOS by managing the entirety of an individual window and the layout/content/interaction of the views within.

In your case, I would use an `NSWindowController` - though if the app is very simple, the `App Delegate` works too; and if the app is very complex, then using a `NSViewController` to split up the code wouldn't be a bad idea.

The best way to do use an `NSWindowController` would be to programatically load it in the App Delegate using `[[CustomWindowController alloc] init]` and

```
@implementation CustomWindowController
- (id)init
{
    self=[super initWithWindowNibName:@"CustomWindowNibName"];
    if(self)
    {
        //perform any initializations
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Or calling

```
[[CustomWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"CustomWindowNibName"];
```

directly (and overriding initWithWindowNibName) if you want it to be reusable.

And you can delete the default window in MainMenu.xib.

---

Fundamentally, more often than not, an NSWindowController manages a window instantiated in its own nib file. The NSWindowController usually owns that nib file. (Though it is possible to have it manage a programmatically created window, that isn't usually how it's done.)

To be able to use a custom `NSWindowController`, you therefore need to make your window-to-be-managed in a separate nib/xib file. (using the default xib file means that you allow Cocoa to automatically instantiate a NSWindowController without opportunity for subclassing; you cannot use a custom `NSWindowController` with the default NSMainNibFile. For a simple app, just put all the controller code in the NSApplication/App Delegate)

In Xcode 4 at least, the process involves creating a xib with the window template and the custom `NSWindowController` class, instantiating the `CustomWindowController` class based on that nib in -init or wherever and then calling `[CustomWindowController showWindow:self];` (or if that doesn't work, `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:`) to get the window to actually show (in `- (void)applicationDid/WillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` might be a nice place).

To stop the default window from showing I just delete it. There's probably a better way but I don't know that.

Comment: Yeah I figured I needed to use an NSWindowController but I wasn't sure how to hook it up to the NSWindow. I dragged a new window into the MainMenu.xib and set it up but it is already being loaded when I run the app. I also tried using the AppDelegate just to get things started but I don't know how to eg. make my NSTableView look in AppDelegate.m for the NSTableViewDataSource prototype methods. I tried connecting from the table to 'File's owner' and selected dataSource but it fails with an error 'invalid NSTable view data source'.

Comment: The easiest way to hook up the NSWindowController is to split up your nib files and give it its own file to load. So make a new nib file using the window template and set the Files Owner to the controller. Also, about your attempt to connect to the dataSource: 'File's Owner' in that case was the NSApplication; you want to drag to the App Delegate instead.

Comment: Ok so I made a new controller 'MainWindowController' and ticked 'with xib file'. I copied the NSwindow from the MainMenu.xip and pasted it in the new MainWindowController.xib file deleting the old one. The 'Custom Class' of File's Owner is set to MainWindowController. I added custom init method to MainWindowController.m with `self=[super initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowController"];` . I instantiate my MainWindowController property in the app delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method with `mainWindow = [[MainWindowController alloc] init];` .. no errors but no window. Anything I missed?

Comment: `[CustomWindowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]` didn't work but `[CustomWindowController showWindow:self];` did. Straight after `[[CustomWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"CustomWindowNibName"];` in the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method of the App Delegate.

Comment: @TijuanaKez Awesome! I was wrong about `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` then, but glad you found the correct solution.