# Is it possible to have a custom NSWindowController on launch?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nswindowcontroller

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10128268/1087848) answer is said it is possible to have a custom NSWindowController by removing the window from MainMenu.xib and instantiating the window controller 'manually' from `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. But it also says:

> To stop the default window from showing I just delete it. There's probably a better way but I don't know that.

*Is* there a better way? What is that better way, should it exist? Is it considered 'normal' practice to get your own window controller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do this, you would usually subclass NSWindowController and change the File's Owner class to your WindowController subclass in the nib.

EDIT:

If you aren't doing a document-based app, and just want an NSWindowController of your own to do on-demand loading of Nibs (completely reasonable), then you'd delete the window from your nib and instantiate an `NSWindowController` subclass programmatically, using it explicitly to do your window loading...

```
@implementation MyApplicationDelegate {
    MyWindowControllerSubclass *windowController;
}


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    windowController = [[MyWindowControllerSubclass alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowNib"];

    [windowController showWindow:nil];
    [windowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. The initial owner is NSApplication, and you get 2 warnings when you change that. The window does appear, but my window controller's `initWithWindow:` isn't called, as is `awakeFromNib`...

Comment: Pardon me, you don't change the subclass in the MainMenu.nib, you change it in your document's nib.  I'm assuming you're doing a document-based app, I don't think you even get an NSWindowController to replace otherwise, not by default.  If you aren't doing a document-based app, then the best thing to do is indeed delete the boilerplate window, instatiate an NSWindowController subclass of your own devising in applicationDidFinishLaunching: and use it to load your window programmatically out of a separate window-boilerplate nib.

Comment: No, it's not a document based app. But then I'll do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was running into the same issue and I want to show you my own solution.

1. Create a normal Cocoa Application (**not** Document Based)
2. Go to MainMenu.xib an delete the Window
3. Go ahead and create a new file, *User Interface -> Window*
4. After that create a subclass of NSWindowController
5. Open the just created xib file and set the *Custom Class* in the *Identity inspector* to the just created subclass of NSWindowController
6. Right click on File's Owner and connect the *window* property to the actual window
7. Now go to the AppDelegate an create an instance variable that holds you CustomWindowController
8. Last thing you have to do is instantiate your CustomWindowController  `self.customWindowController = [[AccountWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"CustomWindow"];` and show the Window `[self.customWindowController showWindow:nil]` in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

Here is an example project https://www.dropbox.com/s/ft3t7w72806tnoe/CustomWindowController.zip

Comment: While I appreciate you took the time to answer, this is kind of a duplicate of iluvcapra's answer.

Comment: You are totally right. I didn't saw that! Just did the same thing here and thought I answer it quickly.

Comment: @tuna ur answer was more helpful though as it gave step by step guidance

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another way: `NSWindowController` has the method `-initWithWindow:`. Because the App Delegate has a property `window` which is linked to the window from `MainMenu.xib` on startup, it was easy to link it to my WindowController:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    MyWindowController *wincon = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:window];
}
```

I have yet to research this, but I don't get any errors.